# The network's official Twitter account is up and running again. What content do we want to share?

Tags: discussion

Very recently, Stack Exchange has revived [its official Twitter account, **@StackExchange**](https://twitter.com/StackExchange). It had been used intermittently/actually-not-at-all for several years, but now it's being resuscitated for the express purpose of promoting awesome content around the network. As a Community Manager put it, here's what they're looking for:

> - **Awesome/interesting/fun Questions & Answers**
>     We'll feature a few of these per week and try to make sure that they're representative of a broad collection of our sites. This includes notable meta posts, too - though I'm guessing they'll be infrequent.
> - **Site events/contests**
>     If a site has a regular or one-off event, we may be able to tweet about some of them. Some of y'all do events throughout the year and we'd love to share some of the community-led fun.
> - **Users who do noteworthy work or meet celebratory rep levels**
>     *We won't Tweet about anyone without reaching out to them first...* but if there's someone you think deserves (and would appreciate) a spotlight on what they've been doing, either on main and/or meta, let us know.

They're looking for great posts both young and old - I have word that a "Throwback Thursday" of sorts is in the works - and given that people here have written some phenomenal stuff over the years, we definitely have lots to choose from (as well as plenty of new stuff, too). [Here's the first tweet](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/1106246229288251395), which I think is a good example.

### How will this work?

There are a couple of levels to this.

1. First, Android Enthusiasts users will write an answer to this question with a link to the content and a short blurb about why it should be tweeted out to 17,640 people and counting. Alternatively, they can also use [our main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts) to share the idea.
2. Periodically (probably more regularly than I expect), the mods will go through and look at submissions. If we see stuff that looks good - and I bet that there will be lots of that - we'll forward that to the Community Team via super-secret backchannels.
3. A Community Manager will *manually* select posts to be tweeted.

Oh, I have it on good authority that here may be a Throwback Thursday-style set of tweets each week - so feel free to submit some old posts, as well as new ones!

Whatever happens, @StackExchange is going to be a great opportunity for us and the rest of the network. What content from Android Enthusiast Stack Exchange do you want to see on it?

**NOTE**: this post will **not** "expire"! At any time in the future you should encounter a good question/answer, please post it here!

---

<sup>This post was adapted from [Frederico's from Aviation.SE](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3779) and [HDE 226868's from WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7190).</sup>

Comment: Deleted posts ;-)

Comment: So, I'm catching this late November, and, reviewing the activity on the account since March 15, it's, well, abyssmal. Two or three posts PER MONTH, and nothing at all for nearly 2 months.